# Data repository on employee turnover based on Position

Tags: dataset

We need a data-set that has information regarding the career progression and preferably the salary of the employee.

**For example:**

*People move from the position of junior nurse to head nurse (junior developer to senior developer to lead developer etc.) in on average "x"-years. They change job after "y"-year and on average receive increment of "z"-% etc.*

Do you guys know any public or private repository of such data.

Comment: This is probably a better fit at [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you @StephenRauch I will visit [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)